# Django inline formset won't validate

Tags: django, django-forms

This is the first time I am using formsets, and it won't validate for some reason. As I understand it, all form fields need to be non-empty for the form to validate. Are there any other conditions? What could be wrong, there are no error messages, the call to formset.is_valid just returns false when I'm expecting it to be true.

**views.py**

```
PhraseMatchFormset = inlineformset_factory(parent_model=Exercise, model=ExercisePhraseMatch, fields=(
        'is_active', 'givenPhrase', 'matchPhrase'), extra=4, can_delete=True)

exercise = Exercise.objects.get(id=exerciseid)

formset = PhraseMatchFormset(
    instance=exercise, initial=initial_dict)

if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

Validation function is_valid() is always returning false for some reason.

**initial_dict output**

```
[{'id_exercisephrasematch-TOTAL_FORMS': '4', 'id_exercisephrasematch-INITIAL_FORMS': '0', 'id_exercisephrasematch-MIN_NUM_FORMS': '0', 'id_exercisephrasematch-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '1000', 'id_exercisephrasematch-0-is_active': 'on', 'id_exercisephrasematch-0-givenPhrase': 'oih', 'id_exercisephrasematch-0-matchPhrase': 'buhip', 'id_exercisephrasematch-0-DELETE': 'off', 'id_exercisephrasematch-1-is_active': 'on', 'id_exercisephrasematch-1-givenPhrase': 'oih', 'id_exercisephrasematch-1-matchPhrase': 'biuo', 'id_exercisephrasematch-1-DELETE': 'off', 'id_exercisephrasematch-2-is_active': 'on', 'id_exercisephrasematch-2-givenPhrase': 'uiygv', 'id_exercisephrasematch-2-matchPhrase': 'vyui', 'id_exercisephrasematch-2-DELETE': 'off', 'id_exercisephrasematch-3-is_active': 'on', 'id_exercisephrasematch-3-givenPhrase': 'uyv', 'id_exercisephrasematch-3-matchPhrase': 'vuy', 'id_exercisephrasematch-3-DELETE': 'off'}]
```

**models.py**

```
class ExercisePhraseMatch(models.Model):

    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    course = models.CharField(
    default='', max_length=255, verbose_name="Course Name")

    lesson = models.CharField(
    default='', max_length=255, verbose_name="Lesson Name")

    sequence = models.IntegerField(
    default=1, verbose_name='Sequence')

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
    default=True, verbose_name='Active')

    givenPhrase = models.CharField(
    default='', max_length=255, verbose_name="Given Phrase")

    matchPhrase = models.CharField(
    default='', max_length=255, verbose_name="Match Phrase")

    def __str__(self):
        return('course: ' + self.course + ' lesson: ' + self.lesson + ' exercise no. ' + self.sequence)
```

Comment: Please show your `PhraseMatchFormset` code.

Comment: What you see in views.py is the only code that generates the formset.  Is something missing?

Comment: Oh really sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: I believe i may have stumbled on the answer....I've got is_active as a boolean field, but in my initial dictionary, it is returned by the form as "on".  So I believe "on" needs to be changed to True or False, before it will validate.